# The custom cell in the table view does not want to be rounded

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

everyone!

My problem sound like this:
I want to make my custom cell rounded in my app in iPhone. But when I try to do something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? MainTableViewCell
        else { fatalError("DequeueReusableCell failed while casting") }
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.size.height / 2
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.03921568627, green: 0.3969546359, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "EuphemiaUCAS", size: 22)
    cell.textLabel?.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: restaurantNames[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
// MARK: - Table View Delegate
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 85
}
```

I have a strange result: [Result #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H9wb.jpg)

But when I change this line:

```
cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.size.height / 2
```

To this:

```
cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 85 / 2
```

As you can see, everything is in order:
[Result #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG3Ca.png)

But this is not the right way to solve the problem

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1):

Add it in your cell class instead of cellForRow

```
class MainTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
    imageOfPlace.layer.cornerRadius = imageOfPlace.bounds.midY // or imageOfPlace.bounds.height/2
    imageOfPlace.clipsToBounds = true
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but now I don't have a clear circle

Comment: Same issue, nothing changed.

Comment: strange .. it should work ... can you post `MainTableViewCell` code ? and please remove `cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius`  line from `cellForRow`

Comment: i updated my code .. your imageview is smaller then bounds .. so it should be `imageOfPlace.bounds.midY` instead of `bounds.midY` .. tested it in your project ...

Comment: let me know if you need any further assistance :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The problem has come because the `cellForRow AtIndexPath` called before `heightForRowAt indexPath` called. It's a reason why the cell at that time has default height size, and you used it to calculate `cornerRadius`.

You can use your way to fix the problem, or you use the image to look like a mask to put in above the image in the cell. This way can help you use less energy for calculating `cornerRadius` when the delegate is called.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView provides default sizes for rows when you dequeue cells. That's why `cell.frame.size.height/2` is not `85/2` rather than `detaultHeight / 2`. TableView cell height later becomes fix when `heightForRowAt` delegate method called. You can find more about this [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/configuring_the_cells_for_your_table).

Change the corner radius property of imageView in `awakeFromNib` method under MainTableViewCell.

```
class MainTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height/2 
    }
}
```

Comment: in `awakeFromNib` you will not get the exact bound of cell ... its not fully constructed ...